# Insert adding an extra row in database

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

When I insert data from my datagridview to my database an extra row is inserted at the end which contains no data. How can I overcome this issue. Each time I click on a new line in my datagridview and start the enter data, a new line is enabled below. Is there any way I can stop this blank line being inserted into my database? Thanks, here's my code...

```
                    Dim ds As New DataSet 
                    ds.Tables.Add("Main") 

                   Dim col As New DataColumn 

                    Dim dgvCol As New DataGridViewColumn 
                    For Each dgvCol In DataGridView1.Columns 
                        col = New DataColumn(dgvCol.Name) 
                        ds.Tables("Main").Columns.Add(col) 
                    Next 
                    Dim row As DataRow 
                    Dim colcount As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 

                    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 
                        row = ds.Tables("Main").Rows.Add 

                        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns 
                            row.Item(column.Index) = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(i).Cells(column.Index).Value 
                        Next 

                    Next 


                    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection 
                    Dim myCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand 

                    Dim dt As New DataTable() 
                    dt = ds.Tables("Main") 

                    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1 

                        Dim myAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
                        Dim sql As String = "Insert into details (company, division, date, supplier, material_group, cost, dsc, email, userID, fullName, marketingCode, hccNumber, wbs, qty, currency, timestamp) VALUES ('" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(company.Name).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(division.Name).Value & "','" & calendar & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(supplier.Name).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(materialGroup.Name).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(netprice.Name).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(description.Name).Value & "', '" & cmbEmail.SelectedValue & "', '" & id & "', '" & newName & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(markCodes.Name).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(hccNumber.Name).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(wba.Name).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(quantity.Name).Value & "', '" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(currency.Name).Value & "', '" & nowDate & "')" 
                        myCommand.Connection = con 
                        myCommand.CommandText = sql 
                        myAdapter.InsertCommand = myCommand 
                        myCommand.Connection.Open() 
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
                        myCommand.Connection.Close() 

                    Next.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need your check your row for values in your loop try checking each cell (or a specific cell) for DBNull.Value before saving it. Alternatively you can set [AllowUsersToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) to false to prevent the blank row from showing.

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried the `AllowUserToAddRows = False` but when I did that I could not add any rows at all, leaving me with a blank gridview.

Comment: Ok, you need the DBNull check then.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check inside the loop See sample code below

```
For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In Form1.DataGridView1.Rows

            If rw.Cells("Column2").Value <> Nothing Then

                ITM_ID = rw.Cells("Column1").Value
                DSPL_RCT = rw.Cells("Column2").Value
                SLS_QTY = rw.Cells("Column3").Value
                SLS_PRC = rw.Cells("Column4").Value
                SLS_AMT = rw.Cells("Column5").Value
                TAX_CODE = rw.Cells("Column6").Value

                'INSERT A RECORD INTO THE DATABASE

                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO DAY_PLUSALES (DT,ITM_ID,DSPL_RCT,SLS_QTY,SLS_PRC,SLS_AMT,TAX_CODE) values ('" & Form1.TextBox6.Text & "','" & ITM_ID & "','" & DSPL_RCT & "','" & SLS_QTY & "','" & SLS_PRC & "','" & SLS_AMT & "','" & TAX_CODE & "')", con)

                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End If

        Next
```